# Is the order objects are return by a jQuery selector specified?

Tags: jquery

All jQuery selectors return an array of objects. Are these objects always in the same order as they are in the HTML? Can I rely on this?

Answer (score 118, accepted):

Yes.
The [jQuery 1.3.2 release notes](https://blog.jquery.com/2009/02/20/jquery-1-3-2-released/) say:

> #### Elements Returned in Document Order
>
> This is a change to jQuery's selector engine that re-orders the returned results to be in document order, instead of the order in which the selectors were passed in. This change was done in order to be in compliance with the Selectors API specification (which jQuery uses, internally, in browsers that support it).

This wasn't the case on [jQuery 1.3](https://blog.jquery.com/2009/01/14/jquery-1-3-released/):

> The order of "a, b, c" style selectors may change. Browsers that support querySelectorAll (Safari, Firefox 3.5+, Opera 10+, IE 8+) will return the elements in document order, other browsers will (currently) return them in the order specified. In 1.3.2 and later release all comma-separated selectors will be returned in document order.

Comment: Interesting that it is really in release notes, and it also makes sense, but somebody forgot it to put it also in https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/ - dear somebody, please add this info there too :) !

Comment: The answer is really old has anyone found an updated link?

Comment: @DanielLeach - I updated the links, thanks. This behavior should still be correct, it is also document here for the latest version: https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 9):

There may be some exceptions, for example from the prevAll() documentation:

"Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .prevAll() method searches through the predecessors of these elements in the DOM tree and construct a new jQuery object from the matching elements; **the elements are returned in order beginning with the closest sibling**."

http://api.jquery.com/prevAll/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, they're always in the order as they're in the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Probably in the order it finds them, a selector pretty much traverses the DOM and when it finds an element that matches, puts it in an array.

You could maybe do a test by having say 5 textboxes with id's of "textbox_n" where n is a number, then alert the list and see what you get?