# Setting tabindex to "last element" and "penultimate element" - possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, tabindex

In the accepted answer to this question [Multiple submit buttons in an HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48/multiple-submit-buttons-in-an-html-form) the comment is raised:

> Please don't do this without also changing the tab order, so that
>   hitting the tab button will cycle through the buttons as they appear
>   on screen.

My question is: is there a way to set the tabindex on those two buttons to accomplish this ordering **without** having to assign a specific tabindex to every other tabable element on the page?

My understanding of tabindex values is that specified positive values proceed elements w/o a specified value, so I am at a loss to figure out a way to do this w/o going through and assigning everything else a value.

If indeed, assigning a specific tabindex to every item is the only way, is there some (hopefully short and hopefully jQuery) magic to assign every appropriate element on the page a tabindex of, say, 1?

**EDIT**
As it looks like the solution is going to involve applying a specific tabindex to every other tabable object -- it seems like an important part of the solution is going to be: is there a convenient way in jQuery to select every tabable object? All s s s and ???

Comment: did you review [Adding tabindex dynamically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123054/adding-tabindex-dynamically)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Adding tabindex dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123054/adding-tabindex-dynamically) and fixing button indecies:

```
$(":input:not(:hidden)")
  .each(function (i) {
    $(this).attr('tabindex', i + 1);
  });
var r = $('input.r').attr('tabindex');
$('input.r').attr('tabindex', $('input.l').attr('tabindex'));
$('input.l').attr('tabindex', r);
```

html:

```
<input type="submit" value="Next" class="r" />
<input type="submit" value="Previous" class="l" />
```

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/CHk46kXRTppWBycoiMZM?p=preview)

Update - fixed query to select not only inputs (check link in John's comment below):

```
$("a[href],area[href],input:not([disabled]),select:not([disabled]),\
textarea:not([disabled]),button:not([disabled]),iframe,[tabindex],\
[contentEditable=true]")
```

Comment: This is close, but only applies tabindex values to inputs. The answer here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1599660/which-html-elements-can-receive-focus lists all the focucable elements which can have a tabindex. Since I don't want to disturb a pages existing tab order I think the answer is to iterate through all do usable elements on the page and find the largest tabindex in use and then use that value +1 and +2 …

Comment: Fixed plunk with selector from answer you referred

Comment: @JohnHascall tabindex of each element is 0 by default

Comment: Right, if the page has elements with the default value of 0 (reasonably likely).  Then if you put these '<Prev' 'Next>' buttons at the bottom and just give then positive tabindexes, then they become the first 2 elements in the taborder -- definitely the wrong thing to do.  So it seems the only solution is to walk the page, saving a list of the all elements with tabindex 0 and finding the highest tabidex, `H`, then walk the list of zero-valued tabindex giving each of them a value H+1, H+2, ... ending with the two buttons having the highest tabindexes.

Answer (score 3):

According to the specification:

- positiv values assigned to `tabindex` orders the elements according to their `tabindex` values
- negative values make elements "unfocusable"
- a value of 0 makes the element focusable but its order dependents on the platform

[mdn-html specification of tabindex](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/tabindex)

So if you want to have a specific order in your page you have to assign a value to each element.

But here comes jquery:
Say the elements which should be in order are in a `div` with `id="myDiv"`
You can then do:

```
$("#myDiv").find("*").prop("tabindex", 1);
```

This would make every child/subchild element of `myDiv` have a `tabindex` of 1.
Then your two buttons could have a `css` class assigned (e.g: `class="highTabIndex"`).

Then you can call jquery again:

```
var idx = 2;
$("#myDiv").find(".highTabIndex").each(function(idx, element) {
    element.prop("tabindex", idx++);
});
```

and your buttons with class `highTabIndex`would be orderd according to "position" in the page.