# Use jquery to set onfocus event for only img in <a</a> tags

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this piece of code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">  
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <p class="demo">test </p>

        <a href="xx" class="focusme">
            <img src="images/testimage.gif" alt="" >
        </a>

        <a href="xx" class="focusme">
            <img src="images/testimage.gif" alt="">
        </a>

    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.2.1.4.min.js"></script>

    <script>
        $(function () {     
            $(".focusme").focus(function(){
                $(this).img.invert();
            });
    });
    </script>
</html>
```

What I want to do is to invert the images when the `<a>` tag got focus, but I'm stuck to register the `focus` and `blur` event for them.

Here is what I'm trying to achieve :

for example, the html :

```
        <a href="xx" class="focusme">
            <img src="images/testimage.gif" alt="" id="img1">
        </a>
```

So at this point, it's easy to access the img above because it has an ID :

```
$("#img1").invert();
```

but what i want is :

```
        $(function () {     
            $(".focusme").focus(function(){
                var img = $(this).img; 
                img.invert(); 
            });
    });
```

P/s :  the invert() function is from a seperated js file, and is working well if I manually call it like this :

```
$("#img1").invert();
```

How can this be done?

Comment: $("a img.focusme").focus(...

Comment: Sounds like an XY Problem ... what is the objective here? `img` doesn't get focused. Sounds like you want to set an active class or something similar

Comment: @charlietfl I'm really sorry, I was confused, I've updated the question, please take a look at it !

Comment: probably you should use `mouseenter` instead of `focus`

Comment: explain the actual behavior you are looking for...not the invert ... user interaction in the UI. This can be done with css and no js if all you want is hover or touch

Comment: @charlietfl I want to be able to refer to the img object in the `<a>` tag, like I can refer to that img like a object

Comment: users don't *"refer"* on a web page. That is not a behavior

Comment: @charlietfl sorry if I wasn't clear, I have updated the question again.

Comment: you updated it regarding code...but not desired user interaction behavior

Comment: @charlietfl when the user focus on the <a> , the image should invert its color and went back to the inital stage on `blur`

Comment: so use focus on the `<a>`

Comment: @charlietfl that is the problem, I can't figure out a way to "get" to the img if I set the focus on the `a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the focus on `<a>` and use `find()` for the image

```
$(function () {  
    $("a.focusme").focus(function(){
          $(this).find('img').invert();               
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `<img>` tags cannot be focused by default. However, you can allow them to be focused by [setting the tabIndex property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15123054/adding-tabindex-dynamically).

```
$(".focusme").each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('tabIndex', i + 1)
})
```

After adding that, your code will be executed when you click on the images, and when you tab between them.

example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZzzOm?editors=1010