# Multiple selector vs single selector performance

Tags: jquery, performance

I've tried finding an answer, and I've found related question, and while they confirm my findings ([that one multiple selector call is slower than multiple single selector calls](http://jsperf.com/show-hide-single-vs-multi-select)) none of them tell me why.

basically, when you run this code:

```
$("#one, #two").hide();
$("#one, #two").show();
```

Against this code:

```
$("#one").hide();
$("#two").hide();
$("#one").show();
$("#two").show();
```

Then the latter will be faster by about 50%.

However, once we add a third selector, the performance difference is 39% faster.

Fourth selector difference: 26% faster.

Fifth: 30% faster.

Sixth: 31% faster.

Ten: 31% faster.

(Do note these values seem to range in about a 5% margin)

So we get something that looks like this:

[image]

The performance seems to plateau around 6 selectors. It never seems to get any 'faster' than being 31% slower than doing each one through a single call.
Why is that?

Personally, I love using multiple selectors per call, but it seems to have a (relatively) large performance hit. When would this (not) be appropriate to use?

Comment: Interesting.  I had always assumed the first case (multiple) would be faster.  What about class selectors, similar performance?

Comment: That's been my assumption as well, so I was surprised by this. I haven't checked class selectors, but it's worth looking into. I'll run some tests later.

Comment: I'm not sure about *relatively large*. 50% faster will not mean much in the big picture if the reference code already runs under a microsecond.

Comment: Most likely this is due to the difference between sizzle dealing with a single selector or a multiple selector. If it's a single selector and it's an ID or classname, sizzle will pass it off directly to document.getElementById or document.getElementsByClassName. However, if it's multiple, my guess would be it ends up at document.querySelectorAll which won't be quite as fast as the former two methods.

Comment: Note how multi-compound and multi are near identical and are both faster than single-compound: http://jsperf.com/show-hide-single-vs-multi-select/2

Answer (score 6):

In both cases you operates on IDs, so it can be converted to native `getElementById` call.

However, in 1st case 2 additional things must be done

1. The coma must be processed, so there is additional parsing involved
2. The 2 results must be merged, by which operation the [jQuery asserts that they are returned in the same order as in DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636201/is-the-order-objects-are-return-by-a-jquery-selector-specified)

I guess the second operation takes the most time.