# what is fastest: single selector or multiple

Tags: jquery

Which one is fastest?

## single selector

```
$('#main_body').find('[data-table="'+table+'"]:first > tbody > [data-id='+id+']:first');
```

## multiple selectors

```
$('#main_body').find('[data-table="'+table+'"]:first').children('tbody').children('[data-id='+id+':first]');
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1003855/howto-benchmark-javascript-code

Comment: But before you start comparing which one of two ways to do the same thing is faster, you might want to make them actually do the same thing in the first place. `[data-id='+id+']:first` and `.children('[data-id='+id+']')` don’t select the same element(s).

Comment: `.children('[data-id='+id+':first]')` ... now you’re looking for elements with `data-id="123:first"` or sth. like that ;-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17752874/multiple-selector-vs-single-selector-performance

Comment: You can use http://jsben.ch/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a direct answer, I suggest using tools like [jsperf](https://jsperf.com/) and do some test.

Like: https://jsperf.com/what-is-fastest-single-selector-or-multiple.
Which give us:

```
single selector   : 19,992 ±2.49% (ops/sec) fastest
multiple selectors: 16,035 ±3.91% (ops/sec) 21% slower
```

For a full answer and explanation, I presume the first will be always quicker because is a *one function* call agains three.

Comment: jsben.ch is simple and quicker than jsperf.