# Dropzone sorted array send to ajax files

Tags: jquery, arrays, sorting, dropzone.js

I am trying to send the new sorted ordered array into my ajax file.

I am using **JQUERY UI** for sorting the order after sorting I want to get sorted array into my **auction.ajax.php** file.

You can see I also tried to prepare an array. I need to send re-ordered file names array to the ajax page.

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(e) {
    var imageNames = [];

    $(function() {
      $("#myDrop").sortable({
        items: '.dz-preview',
        cursor: 'move',
        opacity: 0.5,
        containment: '#myDrop',
        distance: 20,
        tolerance: 'pointer',

      });

      $("#myDrop").disableSelection();
    });

    //Dropzone script
    Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
    var myDropzone = new Dropzone("div#myDrop", {
      paramName: "files", // The name that will be used to transfer the file
      addRemoveLinks: true,
      uploadMultiple: true,
      autoProcessQueue: false,
      parallelUploads: 50,
      maxFilesize: 2, // MB
      acceptedFiles: ".png, .jpeg, .jpg, .gif",
      url: "ajax/actions.ajax.php",

    });

/*Ans code*/
    myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
      var filenames = [];

      $('.dz-preview .dz-filename').each(function() {
        filenames.push($(this).find('span').text());
      });

      formData.append('filenames', filenames);
    });

    /* Add Files Script*/
    myDropzone.on("success", function(file, message) {
      $("#msg").html(message);
      //setTimeout(function(){window.location.href="index.php"},800);
    });

    myDropzone.on("error", function(data) {
      $("#msg").html('<div class="alert alert-danger">There is some thing wrong, Please try again!</div>');
    });

    myDropzone.on("complete", function(file) {
      //myDropzone.removeFile(file);
    });

    $("#add_file").on("click", function() {
      myDropzone.processQueue();
    });
  });
</script>
<div class="dropzone dz-clickable" id="myDrop">
  <div class="dz-default dz-message" data-dz-message="">
    <span>Drop files here to upload</span>
  </div>
</div>
<input type="text" name="sortingOrder" id="sortingOrder" value="">
<button id="add_file">Add</button>
```

Comment: I don't see a problem description. What problem are you facing?

Comment: after reordering I want to get reordered array with comma separated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [`sending`](http://www.dropzonejs.com/#event-sending) event. This event receives `formData` as a parameter, so you can modify it, and send your data to the server.

```
myDropzone.on("sending", function(file, xhr, formData) {
  var filenames = [];

  $('.dz-preview .dz-filename').each(function() {
    filenames.push($(this).find('span').text());
  });

  formData.append('filenames', filenames);
});
```

Now each call will consist a parameter `filenames`, and will contain the sorted names of all files which are there in the dropzone.

Please see this [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/UvJ3BPPl9nPGuyOQYSW9?p=preview). Though no styling is applied, you can see the names of files in the console when you click **Add** button.

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid -- You just need to append my code to yours, its just another callback function to your dropzone component. You don't need the code written in `stop` function of `sortable` now.

Comment: I am still not able to get reordered array. :(

Comment: This code looks good, I think you only need to call `sort()` method on `filenames` and everything should be fine - `formData.append('filenames', filenames.sort());` - this will sort filenames alphabetically

Comment: @codtex -- I deliberately didn't call it since I jQuery's selector seems to fetch the elements in order of their occurence in HTML page. [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636367/2019247).

Comment: @ZaidBinKhalid -- Is the order not correct, or are you not able to get the array at all?

Comment: @31piy 
1) I drop some images into drop zone works fine.
2) Reordered images using UI sorting works fine.
3) I want to get reordered array now. that I set using JQUI.