# Simplebar scrollbar plugin - Scroll to top / reset position in function

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, scrollbar

I need to be able to scroll back to the top of a page within my ui-routed angular one-page site when a function is triggered, but I've used the simplebar scrollbar plugin as a custom scroller, so can't use the window scrolltop method to take the user back to the top of the page.

I can't use any window/document scrolling method as the container that utilises simplebar is a fixed 100vh container, therefore the window is always scrolled to the top.

I've tried using the jquery method below to reset the position of the scrollbar back to the top, but can't get it working, and there are no error messages in the console.

```
angular.element('#mainContent').simplebar('getScrollElement').scrollTop(0);
```

I've also tried this in plain js, which returns 'is not a function' in the console:

```
var mainContent = new SimpleBar(document.getElementById('mainContent'));
```

mainContent.SimpleBar.getScrollElement().scrollTop = 0;

Comment: Have you found the solution? I also facing the same problem. I create a scroll-able container using ScrollToPlugin. Without the plugin, I can scroll to anchor. But after the plugin, I can't. This sample is suppose demo the solution but I can't get it done. https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/blob/master/demo/stress-test.html

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the `new SimpleBar(xxx)` approach does not work with `data-simplebar` html attribute.
I don't want to initialize the SimpleBar programmatically so I used this in stead:

```js
$('#mainContent .simplebar-content-wrapper').scrollTop(some_value)
```

The actual scrollable element would have `simplebar-content-wrapper` class, and it would be inside the element that you've added SimpleBar for.

The class `simplebar-content-wrapper` was mentioned in its [documentation](https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar/tree/master/packages/simplebar#noscript-support) and can be expected to be consistent across versions.

There would be problem if you have cascaded SimpleBars. Solutions:

1. `$('#mainContent .simplebar-content-wrapper')[0].scrollTop = some_value`: This would only scroll the correct SimpleBar because the elements returned by nowaday JQuery [is in document order](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1636367/9399618).
2. `$('#mainContent>>>>.simplebar-content-wrapper').scrollTop(some_value)`: The hierarchy of `SimpleBar` components is not guaranteed to be unchanged in future versions and this may fail in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution. You can access scroll element:

```
const el = new SimpleBar(document.getElementById('layout'));
el.scrollContentEl.scrollTop = 0;
```

Comment: is this the same HTML element that has the `data-simplebar` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

You can try .animate for this:

```
$("body").animate({ scrollTop: 0 }, "slow");
```

Comment: Please read the question. The body/window cannot be animated because it is always at the top, the simplebar div is a fixed 100vh height, therefore window/document scrolling won't work.

Answer (score 0):

```
var el = new SimpleBar(document.getElementById('myElement'));
el.getScrollElement().scrollTop = 0;
```